# Как посчитать ROW_NUMBER() OVER() c условием пересечения по времени?

Tags: sql, bigquery

У меня есть таблица.
Вот пример:

| profile_id | starts_at | ends_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| kevinliugrateful | 2010-04-01 00:00:00 UTC | 2013-01-01 00:00:00 UTC |
| kevinliugrateful | 2010-06-01 00:00:00 UTC | 2011-10-01 00:00:00 UTC |
| kevinliugrateful | 2014-06-01 00:00:00 UTC | 2015-06-01 00:00:00 UTC |
| kevinliugrateful | 2014-09-01 00:00:00 UTC | 2015-01-01 00:00:00 UTC |
| kevinliugrateful | 2018-09-01 00:00:00 UTC | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 UTC |

Выше - таблица рабочего опыта человека, с указанием даты начала и даты конца работы на рабочем месте. Это данные одного человека, но в реальнойтаблице есть данные по большому количеству пользоваталей.

Мне необходимо сделать нумерацию опытов, таким образом, чтобы пересекающиеся опыты имели один и тот же номер.

Т. е. на выходе должно быть что-то вроде:

| profile_id | starts_at | ends_at | exp_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| kevinliugrateful | 2010-04-01 00:00:00 UTC | 2013-01-01 00:00:00 UTC | 1 |
| kevinliugrateful | 2010-06-01 00:00:00 UTC | 2014-01-01 00:00:00 UTC | 1 |
| kevinliugrateful | 2014-06-01 00:00:00 UTC | 2015-06-01 00:00:00 UTC | 2 |
| kevinliugrateful | 2014-09-01 00:00:00 UTC | 2015-01-01 00:00:00 UTC | 2 |
| kevinliugrateful | 2018-09-01 00:00:00 UTC | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 UTC | 3 |

Я понимаю, что это надо делать с помощью `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()`, но не понимаю, как указать условие, чтобы номер менялся тогда, когда появляется опыт, который не пересекается с предыдущими.
Запрос я делаю в `BigQuery`, но реализация на уровне `SQL` мне тоже подойдет:)

Благодарю

Comment: Сначала надо выполнить объединение диапазонов. Поиск поможет, задача стандартная и несложная. Ну а потом просто группировка по вхождению в объединённый диапазон.

Comment: Пересекающиеся диапазоны всегда один внутри другого или может быть такое что один, например, 2010-2012, а второй 2011-2013?